# Push innerHTML value to data layer of Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, innerhtml

I am new to HTML and CSS so sorry if this has been posted before.

I am building tags for a new website that tracks the number of times sections on a page have been viewed.

The names of the sections are contained in a variable called "innerHTML" of the h2.title. I can't seem to push this into the dataLayer for Tag Manager to use in triggers.

How do I go about this?

[image: here is an image of the HTML code]

[image: and the variable in GTM]

Comment: Do you have a code sample? Can you post it so we can see what you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Element Visibility Trigger Type
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961#element_visibility
If you'd like to stuck with Dom variable here is some explanation of how it works:
By default the DOM Element variable returns the text content of selected element. That seems to be the same as innerHTML in your case.
So you may just use this variable as the condition in the trigger.
Here is an example.
I have a tag on my page
`<h1 id="title">test page 1</h1>`
and I created a DOM element variable
[image]
This variable resolves to 'test page 1'
[image]
Now I can use this as a condition in my trigger
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this Javascript code in your page HTML.

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('h2.title');
    for(i=0;i<sections.length;i++)
    {
        if (checkVisible(sections[i])) {
            var sectionTitle = sections[i].innerText;
            if(dataLayer.length == 0 || dataLayer[dataLayer.length-1]["sectionTitle"] != sectionTitle){
                dataLayer.push({"sectionTitle":sectionTitle });
            }
        }
    }
});

function checkVisible(elm) {
    var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
    return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

This code is pushing title to dataLayer with key "sectionTitle" if section title is visible in the users screen.

Then you can read datalayer in GTM and setup propper tags/triggers

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for this, but when I try to load this script it tells me: Error at line 2, character 42: Parse error. ')' expected

Comment: How are you trying to load it? My javascript code above doesn't have issues and working fine for me.